# Change string in file in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I have a problem changing a file in python. I need to change a string.
The file is not a text file but can be edited with a text editor.

Here is my code:

```
with open(esp,"r") as f:                
            content=f.readlines()         
with open(esp_carsat,"w") as f:
        for line in content:
                f.write(line.replace("201","202")))
```

Problem is that content is in byte I think.
'\xff\xfe<\x00I\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00s\x00>\x00\r\x00\n'

So my replace is not working. I tried to play with encoding but the file is not readable afterwards. Furthermore, I have accents in the file (é,è...)

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *UTF-16 encoded* data. Decode to Unicode text, replace, and then encode back to UTF-16 again:

```
>>> data = '\xff\xfe<\x00I\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00s\x00>\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
>>> data.decode('utf16')
u'<InstanceNames>\r\n'
```

I had to append an extra `\x00` to decode that; by reading the file without decoding Python split the line on the `\n` and left the `\x00` for the *next* line.

Unicode data can handle accents just fine, no further work required there.

This is easiest done with [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to open file objects that do the decoding and encoding for you:

```
import io

with io.open(esp, "r", encoding='utf16') as f:                
    content=f.readlines()         

with open(esp_carsat, "w", encoding='utf16') as f:
    for line in content:
        f.write(line.replace("201", "202")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's UTF-16-LE data:

```
>>> b
'\xff\xfe<\x00I\x00n\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00s\x00>\x00\r\x00\n'
>>> print(b[:-1].decode('utf-16-le'))
<InstanceNames>
```

Comment: The `\xff\xfe` bytes at the start are the *Byte order mark* or BOM. No need to pick either little endian or big endian here, the data tells you itself.